# Density matrix for a diagonally polarized photon

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix

I am struggling with the density matrix for diagonally polarized photons. Can I think of diagonally polarized photons as a mixture of vertically and horizontally polarized photons?

Comment: **Related**: [Density matrices for pure states and mixed states](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/density-matrices-for-pure-states-and-mixed-states)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write a diagonally polarized state as a linear *superposition* of horizontally and vertically polarized states ("mixture" isn't the right term though; it's still a [pure state](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/whats-the-difference-between-a-pure-and-mixed-quantum-state)). For instance, the $45^{\circ}$ diagonally polarized state $\lvert \nearrow \rangle$ may be expressed as 
$$\lvert \nearrow \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \lvert \rightarrow \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\lvert \uparrow \rangle.$$

The density matrix $\rho$ of this state can be written as $\lvert\nearrow\rangle\langle \nearrow\rvert$ (cf. [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/density-matrices-for-pure-states-and-mixed-states)); try calculating the matrix notation by yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much!